# android- OnClickListener not work for views inside recycle adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a recycle view adapter , I've implement addOnItemTouchListener to listen for each row and it works fine .

But I have two buttons in one of my rows and I've set on OnClickListener for them but it's not triggered . this is my code :

```
holder.register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx,Register.class));
                }
            });
```

I've set android clickable for my buttons but it didn't make any change :

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
```

How can I call on click listener for my buttons instead of recycle view TouchListener ?

Comment: show your xml and adapter class

Comment: post your entire adapter code and xml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as you said you have implemented `TouchListener` for each row. so your entire row listens to touch even, so another touch event in the same row gets affecting.

You need to override the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` for each child, otherwise, it will remain an `onTouchEvent` for the parent.

Better implement your `onClick` events in view holder itself. Use `OnclickListener` instead of `TouchListener`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try below. 
remove `android:clickable` from xml. and try `setOnClickListener`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Comment: can i know why you set onTouchListner for your list item??

Answer (score 0):

try this way and remove click event `android:clickable="true"` from xml file and add below code inside bindview holder

```
holder.detailimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a snippet

```
// adaptor 
    public class youradaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<youradaptor.ViewHolder>
    {

    // create variable

    OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) 
    {
       holder.register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
               mOnItemClickListener.click(position);
           }
       });
    }

    //interface for Click-listener
    public interface OnItemClickListener
     {
       // method name which you can call in main class
       void click(int position);
     }
     public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) 
     {
         mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
     }
}
```

in the main class

```
youradaptorvarialble.setOnItemClickListener(new BrandProductGridAdapter.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void clcik(int position) 
    {
    // write you action here
    // enter code here
    }
});
```